# AWS Linux 2 AMI Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-linux-2

I have an AWS Linux 2 AMI EC2 instance.

When running `systemctl --user status` I get the message:

`Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory`

I then ran `systemctl start dbus.socket`, which gave me this message:

`Failed to start dbus.socket: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files See system logs and 'systemctl status dbus.socket' for details.`

I then ran `systemctl status dbus.socket -l` which returned this:

```
dbus.socket - D-Bus System Message Bus Socket
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-03-31 21:26:42 UTC; 14h ago
   Listen: /run/dbus/system_bus_socket (Stream)

Mar 31 21:26:42 ip-10-0-0-193.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Mar 31 21:26:42 ip-10-0-0-193.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
```

Running `sudo systemctl --user status` gives a different error:

`Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused`

I'm unsure of what to investigate next or what steps to take to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hello friend, I solve this, but my architecture it is not the same as yours. I was using a Docker container with an `amazonlinux:2` image and I encounter with this same problem. In some hours I will create a post exposing the solution to my problem in order to show you how I solve it. In any case the solution was based on this repo: [https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement)